# PHP MySQL - Best practice for retrieving rows with details

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 tables:

1. master table "writers"
2. details table "books"

Each writer has a list of books she wrote.
I want to get all writers and their books.

What is the better option, in terms of performance, server load and db load:

**Option A:**
One query with JOIN between writers and books, resulting in multiple rows for each writer and then rearrange the data (group in 2 level array) using PHP code

**Option B:**
One query to receive all writes, and then loop through the resultset and do another query for each writer's books (easier PHP code, but 'num-of-writes' + 1 queries)

**Option C:**
Any other suggested solution?

Thank you

Comment: for perfomance the better is option  A  .. one db query only  a  single loop in php

Comment: Almost certainly A is the most efficient, if you order the query by writer first, then for the grouping you can simply keep looping until you find the writer ID has changed, then start the next group.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Option A is virtually always the better choice, if you already know you need all the joined data, and the join is well-optimized with indexes.

Option B is such a common anti-pattern that it has a name: **The SELECT N+1 Problem.** It's notorious for killing performance in web applications.

The problem is that *you don't know how many queries your code will run*, because you could fetch multiple writers in your outer loop, and each writer may have written many books. You could be querying for [Erle Stanley Gardner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erle_Stanley_Gardner)!

Here's a nice ebook about [Solving the N+1 Problem](https://leanpub.com/sn1php) by Paul M. Jones, or watch Paul give a presentation about this topic here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fca-Ng0bzuk